# "Too much contention" when creating new entity in dataStore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

This morning my GAE application generated several error log: "too much contention on these datastore entities. please try again.". In my mind, this type of error only happens when multiple requests try modify **the same entity** or entities in the **same entity group**.

When I got this error, my code is inserting new entities. I'm confused. Does this mean there is a limitation of how fast we can create new entity?

My code of model definition and calling sequence is show below:

```
# model defnition
class ExternalAPIStats(ndb.Model):
    uid = ndb.StringProperty()
    api = ndb.StringProperty()
    start_at = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    end_at = ndb.DateTimeProperty()

# calling sequence
stats = ExternalAPIStats(userid=current_uid, api="eapi:hr:get_by_id", start_at=start_at, end_at=end_at)
stats.put()  # **too much contention** happen here
```

That's pretty mysterious to me. I was wondering how I shall deal with this problem. Please let me know if any suggestion.

Comment: I have same issue. I'm using pipelines. I `put()` a new entity when running the pipeline. My code is not wrapped in a transaction (not of my own making anyway) but the line where I `put` is surfacing as `TransactionFailedError(too much contention on these datastore entities. please try again.)` I haven't been able to find an explanation for this behaviour in the docs

Comment: I only just noticed that this is a new bounty on a year-old question. :) Anentropic, are you creating entities using keys with a common ancestor?  Creating new entities in the same entity group is equivalent to making concurrent changes to the same group, and these will contend for access even if you're not using an explicit transaction.  (Each operation is in its own implicit transaction if there is no explicit transaction.)  If you don't believe you're using a common ancestor in the keys, can you post your code, possibly on a new question?

Comment: @DanSanderson  actually I was, I thought I wasn't but it turned out I was. It seems it's still possible to get contention of the kind described by OP though, due to 'hot tablets' issue... I found that article that Bruyere posted as answer and it is also buried in the docs somewhere

Comment: oh, I see you already replied to that :)

Comment: Yeah, I got someone to confirm that contention errors are strictly about contention, and hot tablets will result in slowness or possibly timeouts.  Glad it worked out!

Answer (score 21):

Without seeing how the calls are made(you show the calling code but how often is it called, via loop or many pages calling the same put at the same time) but I believe the issue is better explained [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/scalability). In particular

> You will also see this problem if you create new entities at a high rate with a monotonically increasing indexed property like a timestamp, because these properties are the keys for rows in the index tables in Bigtable.

with the 'start_at' being the culprit. This [article](http://ikaisays.com/2011/01/25/app-engine-datastore-tip-monotonically-increasing-values-are-bad/) explains in more detail.

Possibly (though untested) try doing your puts in batches. Do you run queries on the 'start_at' field? If not removing its indexes will also fix the issue.

How is the puts called (ie what I was asking above in a loop, multiple pages calling)? With that it might be easier to narrow down the issue.

Comment: The issue of "hot tablets" due to nearby property index rows shouldn't cause a contention error, only slowness at high QPS, and a deadline-exceeded error in the worst case.  Good to mention it, though.  (I'll ask around in case slowness might be reported as a contention error in some cases.  Seems like it might...)

Answer (score 6):

Here is everything you need to know about Datastore Contention and how to avoid it:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/scaling/contention?hl=en
**(Deleted)**

***UPDATE:***
You are reaching writes per second limit on the same entity group. Default it is 1 write per second.
https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/limits

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47800087/1034622

Comment: this doesn't answer the question: as far as I can understand from the docs, when you create a new ancestor-less entity you create a new entity group, so how is it possible to get contention when creating? it seems like the docs barely scratch the surface of "what you need to know about Datastore Contention"

Comment: Link no longer navigates to anywhere valuable