# How can I trap for the 409 error on too much contention when updating an entity in Google Datastore

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore, contention

Every few days, on Google Datastore, when I update an entity then I receive the error "Aborted: Too much contention when updating entity". It is certainly possible that other streams could be accessing the entity at the same time. Related questions have been asked over the past 10 years and I can't find an answer, also maybe there are some newer options available. For an early example, see

["Too much contention" when creating new entity in dataStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308179/too-much-contention-when-creating-new-entity-in-datastore)

Consider a very basic update:

```
    average_data = codecs.encode(json.dumps(json_data).encode('utf-8'), encoding='zlib_codec')
    with client.transaction():
        entity = client.get(key)
        entity["average_data"] = average_data
        client.put(entity)
```

How can I best trap for a 409 exception? The client.put() method doesnt seem to actually return anything. I could try something like this, although it a bit seems dumb:

```
average_data = codecs.encode(json.dumps(json_data).encode('utf-8'), encoding='zlib_codec')
with client.transaction():
    entity = client.get(key)
    entity["average_data"] = average_data
    try:
       client.put(entity)
    except:
       try:
          sleep(0.1)
          client.put(entity)
       except:
          sleep(0.5)
          client.put(entity)
```

But maybe that is indeed the best option?

Thanks,

Comment: It is expected behaviour. To avoid this issue, you can modify the code in order to make sure that the same entity is not updated more than once per second. Also keep in mind that the maximum size for an entity is 1,048,572 bytes. You can check the limits in this [docs](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/limits). Also refer to this [datastore best practices](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/best-practices#indexes).

Comment: Hi Sarah, I don't think I have an easy way of knowing if a user somewhere has recently updated something. I do anticipate that any updates will be infrequent (once every few hours). So is a simple repetition of "try/except" the recommended solution? Should I increase the wait times (e.g. make the second "wait" at least one second after the first call?)

Comment: Yes, please try to increase the wait time of a second call after the first call. Let me know if the issue persists.